# "No provisioning profile required" in xcode 9.2, while uploading app on appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, provisioning-profile, xcode9.2

While trying to upload Application on App Store using Xcode 9.2 from system A, it works just fine but while trying the same from system B with the same code and same Xcode version it doesn't allow me to select Provisioning profile on 1st step. It says "No Profile Required" for App file.

Tried these possible solutions for this.

1. Removed all certificates and installed again.
2. Cleaned project temp files.
3. Re-installed Xcode 9.2.

Here are the screenshots of what I am getting in the xcode 9.2

System A -

[image]

System B -

[image]

Error I am getting on System B is -

[image]

Expected Results: 
Upload process should work on System B same as System A.

Actual Results:
While trying to upload Application on App Store using Xcode 9.2 from system A, it works just fine but while trying the same from system B with the same code and same Xcode version it doesn't allow me to select Provisioning profile on 1st step. It says "No Profile Required" for App file.

Version/Build: Xcode 9.2

Comment: Are you sure that is the error message? Can you show a screenshot of the errror.  I've heard of missing provisioning profiles or not found, but never a message saying that "No profile required".

Comment: @wottle added screenshot of the exact error, please review.

Comment: @wottle did you get a chance to see this ?

Comment: I did.  So it's not an error, it's that you cannot select a provisioning profile on machine B, which is causing the app not to be signed.  I have not seen that before.

Comment: Have you downloaded the iOS Distriburion provisioning profile to machine B? It doesn't look like it would even give you the ability to select it, which is odd.

Comment: Yes I have installed the mobileprovision file on system B and its working as I have come to this step after selecting it in "archieve"

Comment: Looks like you are trying to submit the .framework and not the real app

Comment: @jcesarmobile Any idea why its becoming a .framework on system B. Its coming out as app on system A.

Comment: Do you have the correct target selected before archiving it?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yes :(

Comment: reported this to apple for bug.. no reply from them.

Comment: @Saurabh did you get any reply from apple about this issue ?

Comment: @jfalexvijay no update from apple have to start new project and put everything from current project to new project.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with the help of @jcesarmobile's comment above, I finally noticed something in your redacted screenshots I didn't catch.  They are correct.  The reason it is not letting you select a profile is that you are not attempting to submit the app on machine B.  You are submitting the framework.  Because frameworks use the code signing of the apps they are used in, it is not necessary to specify a profile for a framework.

Something is wrong with your archive that is causing it to have the Framework and not your app and the embedded framework.

Comment: Any idea on what could cause this in archive? why its becoming a framework and not app ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  When you archive your project, are you sure you have the app selected?

Answer (score 0):

Try transferring the certificates from system A to system B.

To export from system A:

Go to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts, click the "Settings" icon (bottom left corner, next to the +-) and choose "export".

To import to System B:

Same as the above, only this time choose "import".

Good luck.

Comment: did this but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Add Developer account to xcode then try also make sure you have selected your project and should not selected any third part library

Comment: Did that but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Same issue after transfer of project from computer A to B
However, although it says:Provisioning Profile: None require
And: Signing Certificate: Development (or locally as choice)
Upon upload to the App Store the right signing certificate is added and profile still says none (although all profiles are there).
App got accepted after 3 days (longer than usual) and is fully functional.
Export as notarised app is also functional.
Xcode 11.6

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure that what you are posting is an answer to the question and not an attempt to get help to your own question.